# How to set focusable in a UserControl correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, wpf-4.0

what is the correct value for the Focusable property in a UserControl in case you have a single Control (e.g. TextBox) wrapped inside?

All examples I have seen were about the case where you have multiple Controls wrapped inside a UserControl.

Obviously I want to have the TextBox have the focus, but not the UserControl itself. How do I set the Focusable correctly and what more do I have to consider in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is not working properly ? When I create a single TextBox and make a UserControl out of it I can set the Focusable of the TextBox to true and the Focusable of the UserControl to false and it seems to work quite fine. I can focus the TextBox and not the UserControl.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not working, just trying to find out what is the correct way to do it. I had some troubles with the GotFocus event not bubbling up and checking everything. Just curious what is the recommended setting in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know the correct way to tell WPF that it shouldn't allow focus to go to a `UserControl`.

For example, if you tab through a `UserControl` containing a `TextBox`, it will cycle between the `UserControl` itself and the `TextBox` control inside of it, instead of just tabbing to the `TextBox`

To prevent the `UserControl` from gaining focus like this you would set the [IsTabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.istabstop%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to `False`

```
<UserControl IsTabStop="False" ... />
```

Comment: Are you sure? According to your link: 'It is setting the behavior for the **children** of the element that this property is set on'.

Comment: @LPL Ooops wrong property. One second, I'll update my answer. Thanks for that :)